# Can't initialize variables on strings in java

Tags: java, eclipse

Before you jump at me saying this is already answered, yes I know its answered but all questions are different,on the answered questions they use code that i have still no knowledge therefore I cannot tell what im doing wrong. Anyways getting into my error I get an *error* saying can't initialize variable `String admin2`, basically Im trying to make a password program, I know exactly what I need to change but I don't know what I have to do in order to make it work. Here is the error:

```
public static void main (String[] args){

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    bacon baconObject = new bacon();

     int password;

     String admin;

     String temp; 

    System.out.println("What is your username");
      temp = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your password ");
    password = input.nextInt();

    temp = admin;

    if(temp == admin2 && password == 123){

        System.out.println("Correct signing in......");

    }else{

        System.out.println("Incorrect!");
    }


     }
 }
```

Comment: `if(temp == admin2` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Also you should post your details from error message.

Comment: Think about the error. What it states and means? Why you are not able to initialise it?

Comment: Im trying to make it so that whatever the user types in is stored in temp,and if what the user typed in is equal to admin2 its gonna make a decision.

Comment: I can't figure out strings always theres an error but with integers I get it right...

Comment: if (temp.equals(admin2)

Comment: Your code gives me `admin2 cannot be resolved to a variable` and it is hard to disagree since there is no declared `admin2` in your code. Also please indent your code properly. It is nightmare to read it in current form.

Comment: But what is `admin2`?

Comment: admin2 is basically the test for the user,If the user typed in admin2 then that is the correct "username"

Comment: Voting to close as yet another java String comparison question.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked,and it is another String question but its different,and on the questions there were weird coide that i have yet not achieved sooo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the text referenced by the `temp` variable is `"admin2"`, then you would put `if (temp.equals("admin2"))` instead of `if (temp == admin2)`.

The reason for this is that in the second example (and your version), it is referencing `"admin2"` as a variable, but you want to use it as a `String`, which is achieved by putting quotes around it.

And the reason that you use `.equals` instead of `==` is because `==` compares the actual object that the variable is referenced to, while `.equals` compares the content of the object the variable is referencing.